# Parse.com: I can upload image but I don't retrieve it

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I'm using angular and the Parse.com REST API. When save an image I received the status code 201 with a name and url, but when I try to get image from this url, I get a broken image.
By example this url: http://files.parsetfss.com/e70a8a0f-f675-42e4-8b15-117a6ad959c5/tfss-ccdd1f71-86aa-41fc-86c4-1f0c67e74974-aa-music-blank2.gif

I would be use another way to save images in parse?

Comment: This is not an answer but to let you know that stop using parse-- facebook is shutting it down. Move to other services.

Comment: Oh, yes, I knew about this, but in the next sprints i will do this.